# Nested Virtualization and CSV issues in Hyper-V server Cluster Failover

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10, failovercluster, windows-cluster, windows-server-2019

I have 3 Windows server 2019 VMs,virtualized on Windows 10 pro.  (MAIN HOST)

server 1 is AD/DC/ISCSI target/DNS/DHCP.

server 2 and 3 formed a failover Hyper-V Cluster and this cluster hosts a Windows  10 Pro x64. the cluster uses ISCSI to connect to the Quorum and cluster storage which is hosted on server 1.

so far everything in cluster works fine.

now the problem is, I have created a 3rd VHDX on my Windows 10 (MAIN HOST) and connected it to the Server 1 via Hyper-V's ISCSI (as i've done for the other ISCSI cluster drives). then inside the Server 1 created another VHDX on it in order to share it as a disk to server 2 and 3.

added that drive to the cluster and chose the "add it to the cluster shared volumes" inside cluster manager.

after that i go into my cluster VM (Windows 10 Pro) but i can't find the CSV. "C:\ClusterStorage" does not exist on it. why?

**Live migration, Quick migration, virtualized networking and Everything else works fine in this Nested Virtualized Cluster Failover.**

my VM guest in the failover cluster has access to the internet, to the files on the AC/DC servers, to the Windows 10 pro host (Main host). **i have absolutely no other problem with this setup**, I tested it in every possible way, the cluster manager itself also validated everything with **"success"** results.

I already tired looking for a drive in the Windows 10 Pro guest VM in disk management but there isn't anything there. and i wasn't expecting anything actually be there considering that the CSV should appear as a folder in C drive of the guest VM.

any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 guest is not aware that there are any CSVs. The guest VM will see it as local device. The attached disk should be found in VMs “Disk Management”.

P.S. Here is a good guide for WSFC home lab - https://www.hyper-v.io/setting-windows-failover-cluster-home-lab/

Comment: I'm gonna quote myself again: "I already tired looking for a drive in the Windows 10 Pro guest VM in disk management but there isn't anything there. and i wasn't expecting anything actually be there considering that the CSV should appear as a folder in C drive of the guest VM."